# How to fix bootstrap button display?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, routes

I've created a simple rails home page using the bootstrap cdn.  I have a button on that home page:

```
<p class="text-center"><a href="page/faq" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" role="button">Start Now ...</a></p>
```

It displays properly when I access the page as follows:  `localhost:3000/message/home`

BUT, the button does not display properly when I access the page like this: `localhost:3000/`

My routes.rb file looks like this:

```
  resources :messages
  get 'message/home'
  root 'message#home'
```

Specifically, when the button displays properly there is a blue background and white text.  When I hover over it, the button background turns darker blue.  This is good.

However, when I access the page via the root route, the button text is "grayed out" and hard to read.  It turns to white when I hover over it (which is fine).  I do not understand why the button text is grayed out when I access the page via the root route.  I would like to get the same behavior using the root route that I get using the other route.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get in chrome console?

Comment: I don't get an error.